# Do I need to define comparer for values inside sortedDictionary?

Tags: c#, sorteddictionary

I have sortedDictionary where key is float and value is some class i wrote. I try to use myDictionary.Max(), but I get an argument exception:

```
ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.
System.Collections.Comparer.Compare (System.Object a, System.Object b) (at <d6232873609549b8a045fa15811a5bd3>:0)
System.Collections.Generic.ObjectComparer`1[T].Compare (T x, T y) (at <d6232873609549b8a045fa15811a5bd3>:0)
System.Linq.Enumerable.Max[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) (at <109e781b32ec464d8737a667de805742>:0)
```

Isn't it that I don't need custom comparer if I use generic as key?

Comment: Have you considered using a [`SortedSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1) instead? It has a built-in `Min` property. The LINQ `Min` operator doesn't take advantage of the "sorted" property of the collection, so it's O(n) instead of O(log n).

Comment: Wait, really? Thanks, I will try that rn

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You mean I should do something like 
SortedSet<KeyValuePair<float, myClass>>?

Comment: Yes, or a `SortedSet<(float, myClass)>`. And pass a custom `IComparer<(float, myClass)>` that compares only the `float`. This assuming that all entries have unique `float` values, because this collection does not allow duplicate elements.

Comment: You could also consider using the [`PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2) class (.NET 6). It has a smaller memory footprint than the `SortedSet<T>`, but it supports a narrower range of operations.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm using unity so I don't have access to .NET 6 but after playing around with SortedSet I decided to use PriorityQueue ported into single independent script which I found online. It is way better for what I needed it for, than SortedSet was

Comment: If you think that your solution can be useful to someone else, you could consider posting it as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).